# Sync checkbox click in html to content of markdown editor

Tags: javascript, events, markdown, event-listener, codemirror

I'm using codemirror and marked as mardown editor and renderer in a side by side view in my browser. I've enabled the gfm mode in codemirror to allow for todo lists and now i want so sync a change back from the rendered markdown back to the content in the markdown editor.
[image: Codemirror left, rendered markdown on the right]

When clicking on one of the checkboxes on the right obviously nothing is happening in the editor on the left.
Is there a clever way to sync the click/change on the rendered part back to the editor?

My best guess is to attach a eventlistener to each of the rendered checkboxes and on a click on one of them, count from the start which checkbox it is and then replace the corresponding checkbox markdown at the same position in all of the markdown checkboxes on the left.

But in not sure on how to do either of this!?
How do I easily add event listeners to all checkboxes?
How can i handle the event listeners when the editor changes its content and the markdown html is rendered again?
How do I get the count of the clicked checkbox when an event listener is triggered?

I' currently using vuejs and would like to use a solution that is not reliant on jquery,

The Part with replacing the text occurrence got answered in another post [Replace nth occurrence of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499498/replace-nth-occurrence-of-string)

I hope you can help me with the problem.

Thanks

Comment: You'd not only need to add the event handlers once, but every time your content changes. So at best you'll implement that when updating the rendered view. Finding the position of the checkbox means just comparing the checkbox of your selection event with the list of checkboxes in the rendered view.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution:

Add and remove event listeners on (re)render of viewer:

```js
        this.codeMirror.on('change', (cm, change) => {
            const notes = this.$refs.viewer.querySelectorAll('input');
            notes.forEach(n => {
                n.removeEventListener('change', this.checkboxChange);
            });

            this.renderedContent = marked(cm.getValue());
            Vue.nextTick().then(() => {
                const notes = this.$refs.viewer.querySelectorAll('input');

                notes.forEach(n => {
                    n.addEventListener('change', this.checkboxChange);
                })
            });
```

Get the clicked checkbox and replace the correspondig markdown:

```js
        checkboxChange(event) {
            const elements = [...this.$refs.viewer.querySelectorAll('input')];
            const index = elements.findIndex(n => n === event.originalTarget);
            let markdown = this.codeMirror.getValue();

            if (event.target.checked) {
                markdown = replaceNth(markdown, /\- \[[x|\s]\]/gmi, "- [x]", index + 1);
            } else {
                markdown = replaceNth(markdown, /\- \[[x|\s]\]/gmi, "- [ ]", index + 1);
            }

            this.codeMirror.setValue(markdown);
        }
```

Replace the nth occurrence of string:

```js
const replaceNth = (haystack, searchRegex, replace, index) => {
    let occurrence = 0;
    return haystack.replace(searchRegex, (match) => {
        console.log('match', match);
        occurrence++;
        if (occurrence === index) {
            return replace;
        }
        return match;
    });
```

};